# LF produced from string not containing it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, newline

If I run

```
select char(13) -- carriage return CR
```

and copy-paste the resulting single cell....

[image]

...to my trusty notepad++, I see CR+LF:

[image]

Who "smuggles" the LF in? The ssms output grid? The OS(windows)? Notepad++? I am not sure how to trace this.

Comment: I suspect this is either SSMS when you copy it, or something else adding it; the data itself will not contain a Line Break as well.

Comment: I confirm that the data does not contain it. The question is the result of much debugging of why a replace on char(13)+char(10) would not work on a case where data had only char(13) but when I checked (from output, and even generate scripts(!!)) I saw both chars there.

Comment: My guess is SSMS seeing the Carriage Return character in the data grid, and on copy replacing it with CR LF (due to the setting about retaining them). I also replicate the behaviour in ADS when *copying*. I also replicate the behaviour for `CHAR(10)`.

Comment: To show behaviour is [replicated](http://larnu.uk/i/25Y76xdrRY.gif) on ADS as well.

Comment: @Larnu, this animated demonstration is great :-)

Comment: Interesting observation, try this: `PRINT '"'+CHAR(13)+'"'`